# Opengl slowdown on 2nd display (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, opengl

I have an OpenGL (4.3) application running on Ubuntu 14.04 using nvidia-355 drivers. Everything runs fine, but when I attach a 2nd display (or remove the 2nd display), the main display will go black and come back. When it comes back, the application slows down considerably (timings show a 2-3x slowdown). Now if I delete and recreate all the GL resources while keeping the same context, everything returns to normal. Question is any thoughts on why the slowdown occurs in that case scenario?

I checked the context pointer before and after and it's always the same. Granted context might still have been lost and recreated, since I am using an earlier version of GLEW, I can't use glGetGraphicsResetStatusARB to check the status. Any thoughts on if any other means to do something similar?

UPDATE: I've tracked down the cause to be a vao/vbo i have. it's a buffer for a draw call that uses points, and it contains a decent number of vertices (in the order of millions). If I keep everything constant, but reupload that vbo, the performance is fine. 2 questions: any idea why this could be happening? Is there a way to detect a display is added/removed in glx/gl/glut? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Direct3D, where loosing the context is a thing that can happen, the OpenGL API contract asserts, that a context is never lost; any housekeeping, like reinitializing the GPU and all associated objects has to happen transparently behind the scenes.

There are several possible reasons for the slowdown you experience. My best bet would be, that some of Ubuntu's convenience automatisms may do something that throws off the internal state management of the GPU driver leading to sub par performance. Without those automatisms newly connected displays won't be activated automatically, but user interaction would be required.

Another possibility is, that with the new display you'll get only the lowest common denominator for the refresh frequencies and with V-Sync enabled thus experience the slowdown.

However I'm only guessing here, and without a deep look with a profiler into your particular system it's hard to tell what's going on.

Comment: I've tracked down the cause to be a vao/vbo i have. it's a buffer for a draw call that uses points, and it contains a decent number of vertices (in the order of millions). If I keep everything constant, but reupload that vbo, the performance is fine. 2 questions: any idea why this could be happening? Is there a way to detect a display is added/removed in glx/gl/glut? Thanks